# SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Object Model (Smo)

Tags: sql-server

Today I installed SQL Server 2014 Express and Management Studio.

But I can not find the object model in the new version of SSMS.

Please tell me how to find the library `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` and other dll?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Today I installed SQL Server 2014 Express and Management Studio.

It sounds like you installed just SQL Server 2014 Express and Management Studio. [Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Shared Management Objects is part of the "Feature Pack" downloads for SQL Server 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42295):

> **Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Shared Management Objects**
>
> SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) is a .NET Framework object model that enables software developers to create client-side applications to manage and administer SQL Server objects and services. This object model will work with SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014.
>
> Note: Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects requires - Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types, that is available on this page.
>
> Filename: X86 and x64 Package(SharedManagementObjects.msi)