# Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll missing from Assemblies folder

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm attempting to reference SQL SMO in a C#/ASP.NET project however  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll` is not located in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies or
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies.

I've attempted to re-install/repair from [Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Features Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) with no success. Please advise.

Comment: format your question to make it more readable

Comment: Hang on, 130 is SQL 2014, why are you trying to install the 2016 feature pack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Object Model (Smo)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193876/sql-server-management-studio-2014-object-model-smo)

Comment: Even tried installing same items from MS SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack (x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi and x86\SqlSysClrTypes.msi) with no success of getting the dlls needed.